# lodash javascript object assign only with same key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const tst = {
  a: 'A',
  b: 'B',
  c: 'C',
  d: 'D',
  e: {
    f: 'F',
    g: 'G'
  }
};

const tst2 = {
  e: {
    f: 'FF'
  },

  c: 'CC',

  h: 'HH'
}

console.log(_.assign(tst, tst2));
// { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'CC', d: 'D', e: { f: 'FF' }, h: 'HH' }
Object.assign(tst, tst2);
console.log(tst); // same with above result.
console.log(_.merge(tst, tst2));
// { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'CC', d: 'D', e: { f: 'FF', g: 'G' }, h: 'HH' }
```

how can i get result

```
{ a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'CC', d: 'D', e: { f: 'FF', g: 'G' } } ?
```

**Which means, I want to get updated tst object. ONLY tst current key.
assign method has not only problem with deep copy, but also unnecessary key (h).
merge method looks appropriate but unneccessary key is included (h key).
I can handle this for now, using other additional method that I made.**

I wonder that I missed function that implements with one built(lodash or es6) in function call like

```
console.log(someFunction(tst, tst2));
// { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'CC', d: 'D', e: { f: 'FF', g: 'G' } }
```

Comment: [`_.merge`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge)

Comment: nope not work. it still print 'h' key i do not want 'h' key

Comment: The absurd exclamation points, the lack of showing what you tried past one lodash method, and saying you don't want to use any additional functions without explanation what are making me this question is too low in quality to remain open. Maybe you can address some of these.

Comment: hmm, okay I'll fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the closest you will get with a native solution that does not give special treatment to the 'c' key:

```
function updateKeyIfDifferentValue(obj, src) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
      if (src.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        obj[key] = src[key];
      } else {
        obj[key] = obj[key];
      }
    });
    return obj;
}

let tst = {
  a: 'A',
  b: 'B',
  c: 'C',
  d: 'D',
  e: {
    f: 'F',
    g: 'G'
  }
};

let tst2 = {
  e: {
    f: 'FF'
  },
  c: 'CC',
  h: 'HH'
}

updateKeyIfDifferentValue(tst.e, tst2.e);
Object.assign(tst2, tst);
console.log(tst); // { a: "A", b: "B", c: "C", d: "D", e: {f: "FF", g: "G"} }
```

Comment: yep there is no one function solution of this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge).

```
var result = _.merge(tst, tst2);
```

```js
var tst = {
  a: 'A',
  b: 'B',
  c: 'C',
  d: 'D',
  e: {
    f: 'F',
    g: 'G'
  }
};

var tst2 = {
  e: {
    f: 'FF'
  },

  c: 'CC',

  h: 'HH'
};

var result = _.merge(tst, tst2);

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: not work it still has 'h' key.
i do not want h key
this is the result of the _.merge(tst, tst2);
{ a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'CC', d: 'D', e: { f: 'FF', g: 'G' }, h: 'HH' }